# Flutter text overflow in a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Row` with two `Text` widgets in it:

```
Card(...
  Padding(...
    Column(...
      Padding(...
        Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Text'),
                Text('Long text'),
              ],
              ...
```

The output is something like this:

```
+----------------------------+
 Text               Long text 
+----------------------------+
```

If the second text is larger than the available space, I want something like this:

```
+----------------------------+
 Text Loooooooooooooooooooong 
      texttttttttttt 
+----------------------------+
```

but I get overflow error:

```
+----------------------------+
 Text Loooooooooooooooooooong texttttttttttt 
+----------------------------+
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the second text in the Expanded widget

```
Row(
    children: [
      Text('Text'),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Loooooooooooooooooooong texttttttttttt ',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use flex to prevent it from taking the full size of the view

```
Row(
    children: [
      Text('Text'),
      Flexible(
        child: Text(
          'Loooooooooooooooooooong texttttttttttt ',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```